# How to use purchased UI Theme with Django

Tags: django, user-interface, webpack, themes

I'm working with Django framework and I've recently purchased a dashboard Theme in order to give to my application a nice front end. My idea is to  use styles, components, fonts and everything else provided in the Theme through in Django's templates.

The product that I bought is called architectui-html-pro-theme.

According to documentation provided the template is powered by jQuery, Bootstrap4 & Webpack

The installation process of the Theme consist of:

1) Download files
2) Run npm install
3) and then start the application thought npm run start

After all that, what i got is a nice Demo of the Theme running on http://localhost:8081

Great... 
But none further informations is provided regarding how to make the Theme works in My Django application.

It's looks like the Theme installed a lot of dependencies (node_modules directory ) so I think  to make it work in my Django project it is not just a matter of copy and paste the full directory in some "static" folder and  just make reference some main.css style file in my "base.html" file.

I have already asked the provider but no answer so far.

This is the file structure of the Theme:

```
.babelrc
.gitignore
architectui-html-pro <dir>
node_modules <dir>
package-lock.json
package.json
src <dir>
webpack-dev.config.js
webpack-prod.config.js
webpack.config-helper.js
```

I suspect I should do something with webpack, but not sure what to do and how to do it. 
Not sure neither if webpack automatically have done everything needed ( When I ran "npm run start" ) and I'm ready to use my Theme in some way.
On package.json I have found this :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec yarn watch --watch src/pages.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack-prod.config.js --colors --optimize-minimize",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors -d"
  },
```

)

I think this should be something simple like put some "script" or "stylesheet" somewhere in my index.html , and start using the Theme, but can't figure it out .
If someone has had the opportunity to work with this or another kind of Theme to make it work with Django, please advise.

Comment: There are a number of tutorials around the internet about this, you maay want to look at static files for serving css and js from django as a starting point https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I already know that it should be handled as static file. My question is about the template, and the process to get it ready for use it.